# Should view controllers loaded from storyboards be strong or weak?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm more used to using nibs than storyboards, and with nibs, most outlets were weak.

Say I want to do something like this:

```
self.menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
```

Should the `menuViewController` property be `strong` or `weak`?

Comment: strong. Does it work with weak
:?

Answer (score 0):

Should be strong. If you configure it as weak, it will be deallocated on the next line.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly saying I'm a bit confused and my answer doesn't fully solve the issue but discover pretty unexpected things.

I supposed that

```
UIViewController *weakOrStrongViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerID"];
```

Is something similar to -`initWithNibName` method

and we should keep such objects as a `strong` reference.

but when I did the following:

```
__weak UIViewController *weakOrStrongViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerID"];
```

the weakOrStrongViewController haven't been deallocated on the next line. Moreover I can easily  present it and dismiss.

I also discovered that retainCount is: (I know it's not recommended and could be misleading)

```
NSLog(@"Retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)self.presentedViewController));

Retain count is 5
```

This method is purely described in official documentation.

Comment: Th retain count is doubly useless in this case.

Comment: Agree that it doesn't show real picture, but anyway 5 not a random number, and if you use weak reference, something still has reference to it

Comment: Still meaningless.  Of those 5, how many are because the object is autorelease?  How many are an internal implementation detail that you have no control over?  How many are temporary as a part of storyboard instantiation?

Comment: answer original question

Comment: No, the retain count does not answer the original question. If you are doing memory management via debugging, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: actually, my main point was about weak reference and object still alive (I don't rely on retain count)